# Attempting to associate a certificate map with a load balancer throws error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-certificate-manager

I'm trying to associate a new certificate map with a new load balancer configuration in my project.  Unfortunately, when I go to connect the certificate map with the target https proxy, I end up with this error:

```
Error creating TargetHttpsProxy: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.certificateMap': '//certificatemanager.googleapis.com/projects/MYPROJECT/locations/northamerica-northeast1/certificateMaps/MYCERTIFICATEMAP'. Resource '//certificatemanager.googleapis.com/projects/MYPROJECT/locations/northamerica-northeast1/certificateMaps/MYCERTIFICATEMAP' must be in same scope as resource referencing it., invalid
```

My understanding is that there are two possible values for *scope*: `DEFAULT` and `EDGE_CACHE`.  I've stuck with `DEFAULT` as I don't suspect I need `EDGE_CACHE`?

Here's the description for the *scope* field:

> The scope of the certificate. DEFAULT: Certificates with default scope are served from core Google data centers. If unsure, choose this option. EDGE_CACHE: Certificates with scope EDGE_CACHE are special-purposed certificates, served from non-core Google data centers. Currently allowed only for managed certificates.

Personally I don't find this informative enough as it doesn't help me make my decision.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't obvious, and the fact that the error was calling out "scope" ended up being misleading...  When specifying the region in that long URL string, I was presuming my default region for my application `northamerica-northeast1`, when really I should have been putting `global`.

So instead of:

```
//certificatemanager.googleapis.com/projects/MYPROJECT/locations/northamerica-northeast1/certificateMaps/MYCERTIFICATEMAP
```

I instead needed:

```
//certificatemanager.googleapis.com/projects/MYPROJECT/locations/global/certificateMaps/MYCERTIFICATEMAP
```

And now I'm load balancing away!